# How do I find unique file names without their extensions in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

I need to generate a list of unique file names without their extensions or using the shell script command "find"

Say I have a list such as:

```
file2022_col.R1.twx.gz
file2022_col.R2.twx.gz
file2022_col.bwa.bam
file2332_col.R1.twx.gz
file2332_col.bwa.bam
file3442_col.bwa.bam.bai
```

I want a list of unique file names such as:

```
file2022_col
file2332_col
file3442_col
```

I'm trying to use `find -type f -name` but I'm not sure how to construct the option to restrict the find command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simpler to use `cut` command to remove filename extensions:

```
ls -1 | cut -d '.' -f1 | sort | uniq
```

Comment: This seems nice and clean, but it will also pick up any directory names. I only want to extract from file names.

Comment: `ls -1 -p | grep -v '/'` could filter directories. The `-p` flag appends / indicator to directories. Then the `-v` flag only matches files.

Answer (score 1):

```
ls | perl -p -n -e  's/(.*)(\..*){1,3}$/$1/' | uniq
```

or

```
find . -name "file*" | perl -p -n -e  's/(.*)(\..*){1,3}$/$1/' | uniq
```

`find` *per se* is a really powerful command, but its a while since I've used it full functionality.

Comment: Thanks, M__. I'll test it.  I notice you call perl.  I'm hoping to find a way to run it entirely in shell, but this could work too.

Comment: Bash has a regex, so it can be rewritten, but dunno if it has the {1,3} syntax

Answer (score 1):

Use [`find`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html), remove all extensions with `perl`, and make unique with [`sort`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html):

```
find . -type f -printf '%P\n' | perl -pe 's{[.].*}{}' | sort -u
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.

`s{[.].*}{}` : replace `[.]` (a literal dot), followed by `.*` (any character repeated 0 or more times) with en empty string.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes): Quantifiers; Character Classes and other Special Escapes; Assertions; Capture groups](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)